# Why entries in my /proc/iomem are all 00000000-00000000?

Tags: drivers, memory, devices, io

Etries in my /proc/iomem are all 00000000-00000000

The same with /proc/ioports. They're all 0000-0000

Like:

```
00000000-00000000 : reserved
00000000-00000000 : System RAM
00000000-00000000 : reserved
```

I'm running 4.10.3-1-ARCH x86_64

Any advice on how to find out the reason by myself is also welcomed, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `sudo` in front of your command, like `sudo less /proc/io{mem,ports}`

Answer (score 3):

The [patch](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux/+/51d7b120418e99d6b3bf8df9eb3cc31e8171dee4%5E%21/#F0) explains this phenomenon.

```
diff --git a/kernel/resource.c b/kernel/resource.c
index 2e78ead..9b5f044 100644
--- a/kernel/resource.c
+++ b/kernel/resource.c
@@ -105,16 +105,25 @@
{
    struct resource *root = m->private;
    struct resource *r = v, *p;
+   unsigned long long start, end;
    int width = root->end < 0x10000 ? 4 : 8;
    int depth;

    for (depth = 0, p = r; depth < MAX_IORES_LEVEL; depth++, p = p->parent)
        if (p->parent == root)
            break;
+
+   if (file_ns_capable(m->file, &init_user_ns, CAP_SYS_ADMIN)) {
+       start = r->start;
+       end = r->end;
+   } else {
+       start = end = 0;
+   }
+
    seq_printf(m, "%*s%0*llx-%0*llx : %s\n",
            depth * 2, "",
-           width, (unsigned long long) r->start,
-           width, (unsigned long long) r->end,
+           width, start,
+           width, end,
            r->name ? r->name : "<BAD>");
    return 0;
}
```